# Get intent of uninstall app in android

Tags: android, uninstallation

I just want to know about intent of uninstall app because of

in my app when user opens the first screen then the device id will be saved in server side by using php.

When user uninstall this app then automatically the device will be deleted in server side.

For this i prepared code for php for delete device id. So when will i call this webservive.

I tried below code

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 String action = intent.getAction(); 
 if("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED".equals(action)){
   // here i wrote the code of  delete device id in server side
}
```

But it is not working because the intent was not raised. So please tell me what intent will be raise when user uninstall the app or tell me any suggestions for solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: i am not sure but i think that by package manage(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html),you can get package name and run one service at background it check each and every time existence of your app. kind of operation you can do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot get the uninstall intent for your own app. See this thread for more - [Get application uninstall event in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874412/get-application-uninstall-event-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can detect uninstall pop up of any app(including your own app) using Accessibility Service.

```
public class MyService extends AccessibilityService {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {

        if(event.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("check for content in popup which is in screenshot"){

        /**Do your task*/
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
}

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
    info.packageNames = new String[]{"com.android.packageinstaller"};
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
    setServiceInfo(info);
}
```

here in  `onServiceConnected`,  `[![com.android.packageinstaller][1]][1]` represents the install/uninstall app package name(this is system app and it doesn't have any UI so it will not shown to users.).

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
<intent-filter android:priority="999"> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
    <data android:scheme="package"/> 
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

test in Android 4.0 and its works fine

Comment: This wont be recieved by myapplication but by others