# How to click in UI window on Android Oreo (and higher versions) with AccessibilityService?

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, accessibilityservice, android-8.1-oreo

I have followed [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43783674/9708179) to uninstall my app programatically. Everything works fine till Android 7.1. But, when I tested the same on Android 8.1 and 9, this seems to not work, because no click is performed on the UI window.
What is the bug in this case? Has anything changed in these newer versions?

**MyAccessibility**:

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

 AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();

    if (source == null) {
        return;
    }
    
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED) {

        List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = source.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("android:id/button1");
        for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
            node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
        }
   }

}
```

**XML (main)**:

```
<service
            android:name=".MyAccessibility"
            class=".MyAccessibility"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/accessibility_service_label"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name=".MyAccessibility"
                    android:value=".MyAccessibility" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
        </service>
```

**XML (AccessibilityService)**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagReportViewIds"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

---

Test environment:

- Motorola G5(S) Plus - Android 7.1 and 8.1 (Updated)
- Motorola G7 Plus - Android 9.0

Comment: Make sure you have added appropriate permission for it. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES" />` for more refer this <https://stackoverflow.com/a/21854473/10835305>

Comment: +1 by importance of this permission on Android Pie. But to goal of this question (`AccessibilityService` click) still not worked.

Comment: make sure that `adb shell pm list packages|grep -i install` gives you `com.android.packageinstaller` otherwise you have to use `com.google.android.packageinstaller` in the `onServiceConnected` method

Comment: does this help?

Comment: @Lino, not helped :-( and also not have other physical devices here to test, only these two Motorola.

Comment: that's strange because with emulators seem working...

Comment: @Lino, Then this can be a bug on android version of Motorola (physical) devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some tests and figured out when trying to uninstall an application on Android 8 and later, `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED` event fires but `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED` event doesn't fire. In addition, when you call `AccessibilityEvent.getSource()` method on an event of `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED` type, it returns null. So I used `getRootInActiveWindow()` method when `AccessibilityEvent.getSource()` method returns null and in addition on API 26 and above, I tried to handle `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED` event as well. 
Please try this code:

```java
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && source == null)
        source = getRootInActiveWindow();

    if (source == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = source.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("android:id/button1");
        for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
            node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
        }
    }
}
```

I modified `accessibility_service_config.xml` file as well for more accuracy.

```
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged|typeWindowContentChanged"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagReportViewIds"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
    android:packageNames="com.google.android.packageinstaller, com.android.packageinstaller"/>
```

I have tested this code on API 24, API 27, API 28 and API 29 and it worked.