# Sending data to server when android application is unistalled

Tags: android, uninstallation

I would like to notify my server that the user deleted the application. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Check the similar question here. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013823/perform-a-task-on-uninstall-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Get application uninstall event in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874412/get-application-uninstall-event-in-android)

According to this post what you ask for is not possible. Are you by any chance using a C2DM implementation?

Comment: no, do you know if main activity's onDestroy() method will trigger before it starts to uninstall (if app is running already)? I might be able to work with that.

Comment: Test it out. Shouldn't take long to try. Remember to comment back with your results!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is currently no way for an Android package to execute code when it is removed. However, you can register a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for [`ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED) *in a different package* that will be called when packages are removed from the phone.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013823/perform-a-task-on-uninstall-in-android).