# What is cause for this issue "Cannot convert argument of type class org.json.JSONArray" in react-native android?

Tags: javascript, android, json, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to write the plugin to get the applist with package name and icon in the react-native. I'm getting all the required data in the form of JSONArray and the images are getting stored in the sdcard.

I'm using the callback to return the result(JSON Array) back to javascript(Success or failure). I'm getting the above mentioned error.

Please find the java code which is fetching the details as below.

package com.sampleapp;

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager;
import com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageManager;
import com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager;
import com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextManager;
import com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager;
import com.facebook.react.views.toolbar.ReactToolbarManager;
import com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.views.viewpager.ReactViewPagerManager;

public class ToastModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    private static final String DURATION_SHORT_KEY = "SHORT";
    private static final String DURATION_LONG_KEY = "LONG";
    public static JSONArray applist;

    public ToastModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ToastAnd";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void show(Callback errorCallback, Callback successCallback) {
        try {
            //get a list of installed apps.
            PackageManager pm = getReactApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
            List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

            JSONArray app_list = new JSONArray();
            int cnt = 0;
            String path = getSDPath();
            makeRootDirectory(path + "/com.framework.xxx/");
            makeRootDirectory(path + "/com.framework.xxx/Cache/");
            for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
                try {

                    if (getReactApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName) != null) {
                        JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
                        info.put("name", packageInfo.loadLabel(pm));
                        info.put("packagename", packageInfo.packageName);
                        String img_name = "/com.ionicframework.xxx/Cache/" + packageInfo.packageName + ".png";
                        info.put("img", path + img_name);
                        //cheak exist  or not
                        File cheakfile = new File(path + img_name);
                        if (!cheakfile.exists()) {

                            Drawable icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(packageInfo);
                            if (icon != null) {
                                drawableTofile(icon, path + img_name);
                            }
                        }
                        app_list.put(cnt++, info);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.err.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
            applist = app_list;
            successCallback.invoke(applist);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void drawableTofile(Drawable drawable,String path)
    {
        File file = new File(path);
        Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();


        //write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(bitmapdata);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public String getSDPath()
    {
        File SDdir = null;
        boolean sdCardExist= Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        if(sdCardExist){
            SDdir=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        }
        if(SDdir!=null){

            return SDdir.toString();
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void makeRootDirectory(String filePath) {
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = new File(filePath);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();  //make Directory
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In the android.index.js i'm calling the native method as shown below:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var toastMessage = require('./sampleToast');
toastMessage.show(
  (msg) => { console.log(msg); },
   (result) => { alert(JSON.stringify(result)); }

  );

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

But the in the java code while return the applist(successCallback.invoke(applist);) i'm getting the above mentioned error.

could you help me where i'm doing wrong. Thanks

Detailed Error:

```
Exception in native call from JS
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot convert argument of type class org.json.JSONArray
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.fromJavaArgs(Arguments.java:55)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.CallbackImpl.invoke(CallbackImpl.java:27)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at com.sampleapp.ToastModule.show(ToastModule.java:100)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke(BaseJavaModule.java:106)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry$ModuleDefinition.call(NativeModuleRegistry.java:143)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.call(NativeModuleRegistry.java:64)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstance$NativeModulesReactCallback.call(CatalystInstance.java:366)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThread$1.run(MessageQueueThread.java:137)
11-14 09:01:24.780 20592-20624/com.sampleapp E/unknown:React:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When working Native bridges, callbacks should be invoked with `WritableNative` components from the `com.facebook.react.bridge` package.

Instead of a `JSONObject`, use a `WritableNativeMap`.
Instead of a `JSONArray`, use a `WritableNativeArray`.

For instance, with a `WritableNativeMap`:

```
@ReactMethod
public void reactMethod(Callback onSuccess) {
  WritableMap resultData = new WritableNativeMap();
  resultData.putString("key1", "data");
  resultData.putString("key2", "data2");

  onSuccessCallback(resultData);
}
```

In your case, you should have something like:

```
public static WritableArray applist;

// ...

@ReactMethod
public void show(Callback errorCallback, Callback successCallback) {
    try {
        //get a list of installed apps.
        PackageManager pm = getReactApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

        WritableArray app_list = new WritableNativeArray();

        // ...

        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
            try {

                if (getReactApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName) != null) {
                    WritableMap info = new WritableNativeMap();
                    info.putString("name", packageInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
                    info.putString("packagename", packageInfo.packageName);

                    // ...

                    app_list.pushMap(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.err.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        applist = app_list;
        successCallback.invoke(applist);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Almouro. I didn't get you. Can you please explain a bit. You mean say i need to store in key value form?

Comment: When i try to write as you said, its display Exception: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableArray error

Comment: My bad, I didn't read your code thoroughly. I'm editing my answer.

Comment: No Problem brother. Thanks

Comment: @coders I updated my answer, let me know if you can fix your prob

Comment: I have one more doubt, Do you know how to pass events to javascript from the native java in the react-native. For example, when i uninstall the app, i need to send that event to index.android.js

Comment: @coders I guess you could invoke a React native callback from the java code when you receive an event, but I'm not sure it would work.
I'm not even sure you can know when the app is being uninstalled in Android (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874412/get-application-uninstall-event-in-android)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes we can get the events of Installed/Uninstalled of apps. I wrote a plugin to do the same(Which we send the events to JS).

Comment: Almouro, can you post the javascript code to access the Map in this case.

Comment: Can someone point me to the docs for `WritableNativeArray` & `WritableNativeMap`?