# How to get row of sqlite after insert in android and pass it to react native?

Tags: android, sqlite, react-native

I'm new in android, and i'm confused about getting value after inserting some data into sqlite, learning from [this tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/), there's some way to get row by id,

after following the code, I can't Log those value to pass into react native,

here's the code I've tried:

```
//java bridge
@ReactMethod
public void insertNote(String Note, Callback successCb){
  long id;
  DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(reactContext);
  id = db.insertNote(Note);
  Note note = db.getNote(id);
  if(note !=null){
    successCb.invoke(note);
  } else {
    //pass error callback
  }
}

//Javascript code
MyModule.insertNote("Try Insert Note to sqlite", (success)=>{console.log(success)})
```

I want to add callback to show the data already inserted, but above code showing error

```
E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot convert argument of type class com.digifc.sqlite.Note
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.fromJavaArgs(Arguments.java:191)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CallbackImpl.invoke(CallbackImpl.java:32)
        at com.digifc.sqlite.RNDigiFcSqliteModule.insertNote(RNDigiFcSqliteModule.java:79)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

someone can help me to fix the issue?

EDIT:
Reference : [What is cause for this issue "Cannot convert argument of type class org.json.JSONArray" in react-native android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709070/what-is-cause-for-this-issue-cannot-convert-argument-of-type-class-org-json-jso)

try to modify java code like this:

```
@ReactMethod
public void insertNote(String Note, Callback successCb){
  long id;
  DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(reactContext);
  id = db.insertNote(Note);
  Note note = db.getNote(id);
  WritableMap resultData = new WritableNativeMap();
  if(note !=null){
    resultData.putString("Value", String.valueOf(note));
    successCb.invoke(resultData);
  } else {
    //pass error callback
  }
}
```

I got the result `I/ReactNativeJS: { Value: 'com.digifc.sqlite.Note@12d960c9' }` but the expected result should be `I/ReactNativeJS: { Value: 'Try Insert Note to sqlite' }`

Comment: It's using the default (inherited) **toString** method and thus returns the class and pointer (the *@12d960c9* part). You need to override the Note **toString** method so that it returns the respective value.

Comment: @MikeT could you give me some code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`resultData.putString("Value", String.valueOf(note));`

use

`resultData.putString("Value", note.getNote());`

Here `note` is referring to the `Note` class.
The class has a `getNote` method which returns a string which represents the text you are looking for.